# disadvantages of CORBA over sockets

Tags: sockets, corba

advantages of CORBA such as
1: language independence
2: location transparency

i am curious to know what are the disadvantages of corba over sockets

one of the possible disadvantage would be speed

Comment: You're comparing apples with fruit. Sockets are a operating-system level way of communicating with other processes and computers. CORBA is a protocol that allows components on different computers to interact, but which requires a physical way of talking to other computers, ie. TCP/IP, implemented via sockets.

Perhaps what you really mean is, "why choose CORBA over implementing my own object-based communications protocol on top of my own networking code"?

Comment: yeah that is what really meant to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problems section of the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture#Problems_and_criticism) sums up the criticisms I've heard of it quite well.